# Difference between list(LinkedList).head and Node head?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was trying to delete the first node of Linked List using Node head but it did not work while it works when I used list.head?

```
import java.util.*;

    // Java program to implement 
    // a Singly Linked List 
    public class LinkedList { 

        Node head; 
    // head of list 

        // Linked list Node. 
        // This inner class is made static 
        // so that main() can access it 
        static class Node { 

            int data; 
            Node next; 

            // Constructor 
            Node(int d) 
            { 
                data = d; 
                next = null; 
            } 
        } 

         static void delete(LinkedList list,int x){
            Node curr=list.head,prev=list.head;
            if(curr.data==x&&curr!=null){
                list.head=curr.next;
                return ;
            }
            while(curr.data!=x&&curr.next!=null){
                prev=curr;
                curr=curr.next;
            }
            if(curr.data==x)
                prev.next=curr.next;
            return ;
        }

            // There is method 'insert' to insert a new node 

        // Driver code 
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        { 
            /* Start with the empty list. */
            LinkedList list = new LinkedList(); 
            list = insert(list, 1); 
            list = insert(list, 2); 
            list = insert(list, 3);
                    list = insert(list, 4);
                    delete(list,1);
                    printList(list);
                    //There is method to print list

        } 
    } 
    //Output : 2 3 4
```

When I use code above I am able to delete the first node but when I use this code it does not work

```
import java.util.*;

// Java program to implement 
// a Singly Linked List 
public class LinkedList { 

    Node head; 
// head of list 

    // Linked list Node. 
    // This inner class is made static 
    // so that main() can access it 
    static class Node { 

        int data; 
        Node next; 

        // Constructor 
        Node(int d) 
        { 
            data = d; 
            next = null; 
        } 
    } 

     static void delete(Node head,int x){
        Node curr=head,prev=head;
        if(curr.data==x&&curr!=null){
           head=curr.next;
            return ;
        }
        while(curr.data!=x&&curr.next!=null){
            prev=curr;
            curr=curr.next;
        }
        if(curr.data==x)
            prev.next=curr.next;
        return ;
    }

        // There is method 'insert' to insert a new node 

    // Driver code 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        /* Start with the empty list. */
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList(); 
        list = insert(list, 1); 
        list = insert(list, 2); 
        list = insert(list, 3);
                list = insert(list, 4);
                delete(list.head,1);
                printList(list);
                //There is method to print list

    } 
} 
//Output: 1 2 3 4
```

I was wondering that these are the same thing are different, Node head and list(LinkedList).head

Note: Both method work for other nodes, the difference is only for the first node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first one you are passing your list as input and in second one reference to  your head node and if you will notice in first example you are modifying your list's head  if data is present at first node.Here's the code snippet which is doing this.

```
 Node curr=list.head,prev=list.head;
            if(curr.data==x&&curr!=null){
                list.head=curr.next;
                return ;
            }
```

But in your second example if data is found at first node then your are assigning `curr.next` to head variable which is local to the method so lists's head value remain unchanged and when you try to print list in main method again it shows old head. Here's the code snippet from  second example

```
Node curr=head,prev=head;
        if(curr.data==x&&curr!=null){
           head=curr.next;
            return ;
        }
```

So if you are storing your head pointer in LinkedList object then you must modify your value in it.